# Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block: Error: ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I want to run a code in my terminal. " truffle migrate --network ropsten"

1_initial_migration runs correctly, but I have an error for 2_deploy_conracts.js like this:

```
D:\Dapp\proje\proje\node_modules\request\request.js:848
          var e = new Error('ETIMEDOUT')
                  ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: ETIMEDOUT
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\Dapp\proje\proje\node_modules\request\request.js:848:19)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (D:\Dapp\proje\proje\node_modules\eth-block-tracker\src\polling.js:51:24)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:9)
```

This is my truffle-config.js files:

```
const path = require("path");

const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const infuraKey = "08ac778579d74dbaa8d2e3d02e5c0092"

const fs = require('fs');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "src/contracts"),
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/${infuraKey}`),
      network_id: 3, // Ropsten's id
      gas: 5500000, // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
      confirmations: 2, // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
      timeoutBlocks: 200, // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: false // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    },
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },
    }
  },
};
```

What or where is the error? Can you help me please?

Comment: can you pls share the truffle-config.js code

Comment: okay. i added it.

Comment: Can you console.log the mnemonics to see if you are getting the right value. Also do not share any key for your own safety

Comment: Actually, I wrote the mnemonics like this: const mnemonic = "build episode .." But I get the same error again. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember if your mnemonics were incorrect, you would get a different error. Most likely your URL is not correct.

Try this:

```
const webSocketProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(`wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/${infuraKey}`);
const walletProvider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, webSocketProvider);
```

If this does not fix it, instead of wss pass https url

Comment: how can I add this code line into the truffle-config.js. I'm new to this, so this is the first time I see such a structure.